# How is quantum metrology realized in experiment?

Tags: resource-request, quantum-metrology

Are there some lists of the method to realize quantum metrology, or rather, utilizing quantum resources to enhance the precision of parameter estimation. The experimental method I've know is listed as follows:

- [Trapped Ions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01609)
- [Bose-Einstein Condenstates](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01609)
- [Cold Thermal Atoms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01609)
- [NV Center in Diamond](https://academic.oup.com/nsr/article/5/3/346/4430770)
- Some interferometry(e.g. Ramsey interferometer, [MZ interferometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%E2%80%93Zehnder_interferometer))

Comment: Are the links correct? the first three are identical, and the fourth one seems broken. Also, this seems very broad: the review you link lists more than ~500 citations.. it might help to narrow the question a little bit. For a more recent review of photonic quantum metrology, see [*Polino et al. 2020*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.05821). This lists nearly 1000 references, so it should give you a pretty good picture of the current state of the art

Comment: @glS Yeah, the first three links are the same, all can be shown by the Fig.2 of the link. And I've amended the link of the fourth one. And I've also found that the review of [quantum sensing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.02427) has a lot of experimental realization of it. The reason I want to look for those realizations of the experiment is that I want to know what's the main noise in quantum metrology since it's pretty strange that the theory of quantum metrology has developed for such a long time, while the experimental question still cannot be solved clean(at least I think?)

Comment: right, but I think you should clarify *which* experimental question you are referring to. Quantum metrology is a whole field, there's plenty of things that people study and questions to ask. And sure, there's also plenty of experimental realisations of quantum metrology protocols, if that's what you are asking. The above review lists plenty